# How to get r/w permission for a directory for a particular user?

Tags: permissions, samba, sudo, directory

In my ubuntu server a directory named "softwares" is shared via samba for windows clients. The directory has only read permission. I am the system admin working on the ubuntu server. I am also not allowed to modify any contents inside the "software" directory. I need read write permission. How to get read write permission for that particular directory. May i use sudo command ?. And one important thing the permission of others needs to be read only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have admin rights you can prefix your commands with sudo to write to whatever directory, or use chmod to change the permissions.

Comment: i need the exact command to change permission. Give me the syntax

Comment: The exact command depends on the access you want other users to have to the files in the directory. For read/write only privileges to everyone, the command would be `sudo chmod -R 666 /path/to_folder` (The `-R` sets permissions recursively to all enclosed folders and files.) Each number in the command sets the permission for Owner, Group, and World (anyone) in that respective order. Following that command, the folder permissions would read `drw-rw-rw-` where r=read, w=write and x=execute. If you issue `766` it escalates to `drwxrw-rw-`

Comment: @douggro As the directory is shared via samaba, i need r/w permission only for me and not for others who are using windows clients

Comment: `644` would give you read/write and everyone else read-only, which is fairly common for shares.